# moving laravel from local xampp to live web

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have laravel project on xampp and its work great but i want to move it to live web like this : **public_html/laravel** 
right now when i go to **website.com/laravel/public** i get this error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 769:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Establishing tcp connections on remote port 3306 has been disabled for security reasons. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `quotes`)
```

and i couldn't find any answer or even any video to say how make laravel live?

the only thing i change is .env and i set my live database info on that

Comment: "Establishing tcp connections on remote port 3306 has been disabled for security reasons." - I think you need to speak to your host, and double check your database stuff is correct inc. the driver type

Answer (score 0):

MySQL database server default disabled the remote access for security reasons and this is the cause for this message. Check your `database.php` for proper configuration.